Error with Laravel@11 "Unsupported cipher or incorrect key length. Supported ciphers are: aes-128-cbc, aes-256-cbc, aes-128-gcm, aes-256-gcm."
I am facing an error with Laravel@11. The main error looks like Unsupported cipher or incorrect key length. Supported ciphers are: aes-128-cbc, aes-256-cbc, aes-128-gcm, aes-256-gcm.. You can also see in the image.
Error: Unsupported cipher or incorrect key length. Supported ciphers are: aes-128-cbc, aes-256-cbc, aes-128-gcm, aes-256-gcm.
I tried to solve the problem, but I failed. Please help me to find the problem.
Error on browser:

composer.json file:
{
   "name": "laravel/laravel",
   "type": "project",
   "description": "The skeleton application for the Laravel framework.",
   "keywords": [
      "laravel",
      "framework"
   ],
   "license": "MIT",
   "require": {
      "php": "^8.2",
      "inertiajs/inertia-laravel": "^1.0",
      "laravel/framework": "^11.0",
      "laravel/reverb": "@beta",
      "laravel/sanctum": "^4.0",
      "laravel/tinker": "^2.9",
      "tightenco/ziggy": "^2.0"
   },
   "require-dev": {
      "fakerphp/faker": "^1.23",
      "laravel/breeze": "^2.0",
      "laravel/pint": "^1.13",
      "laravel/sail": "^1.26",
      "mockery/mockery": "^1.6",
      "nunomaduro/collision": "^8.0",
      "pestphp/pest": "^2.0",
      "pestphp/pest-plugin-laravel": "^2.0",
      "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.4"
   },
   "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
         "App\\": "app/",
         "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
         "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
      }
   },
   "autoload-dev": {
      "psr-4": {
         "Tests\\": "tests/"
      }
   },
   "scripts": {
      "post-autoload-dump": [
         "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
         "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
      ],
      "post-update-cmd": [
         "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
      ],
      "post-root-package-install": [
         "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
      ],
      "post-create-project-cmd": [
         "@php artisan key:generate --ansi",
         "@php -r \"file_exists('database/database.sqlite') || touch('database/database.sqlite');\"",
         "@php artisan migrate --graceful --ansi"
      ]
   },
   "extra": {
      "laravel": {
         "dont-discover": []
      }
   },
   "config": {
      "optimize-autoloader": true,
      "preferred-install": "dist",
      "sort-packages": true,
      "allow-plugins": {
         "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
         "php-http/discovery": true
      }
   },
   "minimum-stability": "stable",
   "prefer-stable": true
}

Environment:

Windows@11
php@8.2.4
Laravel@11

Question: How to solve the problem?
I hope someone will help me solve the problem.

Try running php artisan key:generate on the command line?

Are you sure this problem is in any way related to Composer or Artisan? Can you also share the code involved, or at least a stacktrace?

Ciao!
If you have not specified a custom encryption key, you could try generating a new encryption key using the command
php artisan key:generate

let me knw
